# Cannot install Win32API::File::Time with Strawberry Perl

Tags: windows, perl

I did a fresh install of Strawberry perl. I am trying to install Win32API::File::Time via CPAN, but I keep getting an error.

```
#   Failed test 'Got same modification time as stat()'
#   at t\file.t line 90.
#          got: 1635942245
#     expected: 1635945845
# GetFileTime: Wed Nov  3 08:24:05 2021
#        stat: Wed Nov  3 09:24:05 2021
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 4.
t\file.t ... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/4 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t\file.t (Wstat: 256 (exited 1) Tests: 4 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=2, Tests=6,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr +  0.06 sys =  0.09 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/2 test programs. 1/6 subtests failed.
Lockfile removed.
  WYANT/Win32API-File-Time-0.012.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe ./Build test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports WYANT/Win32API-File-Time-0.012.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Win32API::File::Time'.
Failed during this command:
 WYANT/Win32API-File-Time-0.012.tar.gz        : make_test NO

cpan>
```

Comment: I can't seem to be about the full output from my CPAN shell.

Comment: Those timestamps differ by exactly 1 hour.  Were you running this during the 1-hour overlap that occurred at the DST-to-Standard Time switch?  What happens if you rerun this now?  Which timezone are you in? What is your locale setting?

Comment: Ran the command today, now.  Check the Windows 10 time zone, it is correct.  Also the times in my original post say 2021 and 24 minutes after the hour, both are wrong.

Comment: Could be a bug. Have you contacted the [author](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32API::File::Time#AUTHOR)

Comment: It's not actually a bug. This is Windows [behaving as intended](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1144/beating-the-daylight-savings-time-bug-and-getting). (Well, the test failing is a bug, but the "wrong date" isn't.) I'll post an answer in a little bit, but you can force install the module safely. (@JimGarrison)

Comment: @ikegami Cool, good find, thanks.  DST changes are the bane of software developers everywhere.  I just submitted a bug to Synology (makers of NAS devices).  If you have a backup job scheduled between 01:00:00 and 01:59:59, it will run twice on DST->ST transition days.  Conversely, backups scheduled between 02:00:01 and 02:59:59 won't run at all on ST->DST transitions.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I am the author, but I no longer have access to a Windows machine. I really ought to Do The Right Thing and put this module up for adoption, but that will not help you short-term. I have not yet studied in depth the link provided by [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami), but I will, and will see if I can come up with a fix. OTOH if you want to be co-maintainer, or even sole author, just let me know your CPAN ID. In the meantime, you can force the install and see if the module meets your needs.